# SQL appending a limit when not specified

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query that is running

```
$this->db->select('Parent_Username, Program_Subtype, Is_Chaperone,Participant_name,Role,Percent_completed,Wizard_ID');
$this->db->where('Parent_Username', $username);
$this->db->where('Program_ID', $Program_ID);
$query = $this->db->get($this->child_table);
```

### an echo produces:

```
SELECT `Parent_Username`, `Program_Subtype`, `Is_Chaperone`, `Participant_name`,
`Role`, `Percent_completed`, `Wizard_ID` FROM (`child_table`) 
 WHERE `Parent_Username` = 'test123' AND `Program_ID` = 'abcdef3423' LIMIT 1
```

So where is that **Limit 1** coming from, when I don't specify it, I need all records, I can set an arbitrary limit like `$this->db->limit('502340234234235');` but why should I have to, why is it limiting it to 1 record when I don't specify it to?

Comment: As the docs states you have to use [Method Chaining](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#chaining)

Comment: @jorgeCampos nothing to do with method chaining the question is why where that Limit 1 is coming from when it's not been specified.

Comment: You must have omitted some code.  In particular, you have nowhere specified the table from which the data should be selected.  Have you also omitted something relevant to the `LIMIT`?